# pandas dataframe sort on column raises keyerror on index

Tags: python, pandas, syntax

I have the following dataframe, `df`:

```
   peaklatency        snr
0        52.99        0.0
1        54.15  62.000000
2        54.12  82.000000
3        54.64  52.000000
4        54.57  42.000000
5        54.13  72.000000
```

I'm attempting to sort this by `snr`:

```
df.sort_values(df.snr)
```

but this raises

```
_convert_to_indexer(self, obj, axis, is_setter)
   1208                 mask = check == -1
   1209                 if mask.any():
-> 1210                     raise KeyError('%s not in index' % objarr[mask])
   1211 
   1212                 return _values_from_object(indexer)

KeyError: '[ inf  62.  82.  52.  42.  72.] not in index'
```

I am not explicitly setting an index on this DataFrame, it's coming from a list comprehension:

```
    import pandas as pd
    d = []
    for run in runs:
        d.append({            
            'snr': run.periphery.snr.snr,
            'peaklatency': (run.brainstem.wave5.wave5.argmax() / 100e3) * 1e3
        })
    df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `by` keyword to `sort_values` expects column names, not the actual Series itself.  So, you'd want:

```
In [23]: df.sort_values('snr')
Out[23]: 
   peaklatency   snr
0        52.99   0.0
4        54.57  42.0
3        54.64  52.0
1        54.15  62.0
5        54.13  72.0
2        54.12  82.0
```

Comment: what if the column does not have a name?

Comment: how can your columns be nameless?