# How to fix KeyError(key) raised by sort_values()?

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

I am trying to sort my df by column values.

tfidf =

[image: input table]

I unsuccessfully tried using the solution(s) provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38810395/pandas-dataframe-sort-on-column-raises-keyerror-on-index).

My code is:

```
x = tfidf.sort_values(by=['174'], axis=1, ascending=False)
```

and I expect the following result:

x =

[image: output table]

but I instead get the following error message:

```
raise KeyError(key)
```

Comment: Try sort without the quotes `tfidf.sort_values(by=[174])`? AND drop `axis=1`

Comment: That was simple.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem could be that your label is not a string. Also, `axis=1` is trying to do the sorting along the columns, but you want the rows to be sorted, so `axis` should be 0, which is its default value.

So, changing the following line to:

```
tfidf.sort_values(by=[174], ascending=False)
```

should solve your problem.

Comment: That is right. I suggest a small edit to the code to achieve my intended output-
tfidf.sort_values(by=[174], ascending=False)